# Why too many connections in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, connection

Recently I've discovered that I have too many connections in my MySQL database:

```
mysql> show status like 'Conn%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Connections   | 39    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show full processlist;
+----+-------+-----------+--------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id | User  | Host      | db     | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+----+-------+-----------+--------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 38 | enrmr | localhost | cakedb | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show full processlist |
+----+-------+-----------+--------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

I've recently installed CakePHP and every time I refresh the main page (F5) the number of connections is incremented in one.
Also if I restart again mysql the number of connections al still 39.

My netstat output

```
netstat -n -a | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR
```

I suppose that I have something like 'mysql zombies connections'. How can I kill them? And how I can stop the creations of new connections every time the web page is refreshed? (Can I only have one connection ?)
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps CakePHP is opening persistent connections but never closing them? I don't know the framework to tell you where to look in the config...

Comment: Why do you consider that number to be too many?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `Connections` is an incremental counter, it's not current connections. It's total number of connections that were established and/or closed to MySQL instance.

If you want current connections look at `Threads_connected`, rather than `Connections`.

Secondly, 39 connections is not much, even if it's a total number of connected threads. It all depends on the application, although just one CakePHP instance will probably utilize just one thread.

Comment: I've seen a single core CPU handle about 150-200 connections per second without going above 10% CPU (Forgetting to make connections persistent probably didn't help), so this number is most definitely not a problem.

Comment: We have a box with 32 cores maxing out at 55000 concurrent connections, so indeed, 39 is not even close to being a load, aside of the fact the the OP looks at the wrong metric :)

Comment: Thanks. I thought `Connections` was the number of current connections.